# JavaScript doesn't write on the page

Tags: javascript

I'm making this game where there are 2 boxes and if you click the right one you win.
I have this problem where when the player clicks on a box it doesn't show if he won or lost and it can only be seen if you inspect element.

I already tried to change the "console.log" to "document.write" but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me how to write something when the player clicks on a box ?

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1')
var button2 = document.getElementById('button2')
var array = [('button1'), ('button2')];
var winItem = 1;

function getRandomItemNum(length) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * length)
}

function recalculateWinItem() {
  winItem = getRandomItemNum(array.length);
}

function checkIsWin(buttonNum) {
  console.log(`Clicked ${buttonNum}. Win item: ${winItem}`);
  console.log(buttonNum === winItem ? "You won" : "You lose");
}

recalculateWinItem();
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="checkIsWin(1)" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; position: absolute; left: 33%; background-color: black; color: blue;">1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="checkIsWin(2)" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; position: absolute; right: 33%; background-color: black; color: red;">2</button>
```

Comment: Where do you want to display the result on html?
place a div with id below the button, document.getElementById('divId').innerText = buttonNum === winItem ? "You won" : "You lose"

Comment: Can you provide html of the page where the result should be displayed please ?

Comment: @Elguti As Shashank said, you have to display the text to the user via an HTML element either, `span`, `div`, `p`, ect.

Comment: @Shashank Add your comment as an answer and I will vote for yours.

Answer (score 2):

Add a container to the page

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

and use

```
document.getElementById("result").innerText = winItem ? "You won" : "You lose"; // or innerHTML if tags in the result
```

NEVER use document.write after the page has loaded since it will wipe the page and scripts

```js
function getRandomItemNum(length) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * length)
}

function recalculateWinItem() {
  winItem = getRandomItemNum(array.length);
}

function checkIsWin(buttonNum) {
  var text = `Clicked <b>${buttonNum}</b>. Win item: ${winItem};  `
  text += buttonNum === winItem ? "You won" : "You lose";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
}
var array = [...document.querySelectorAll("#container .but")].map(function(but) { 
  but.addEventListener("click",function() { checkIsWin(+this.id.replace("button",""))})
  return `(${but.id})`
});
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", recalculateWinItem)
  recalculateWinItem();
})
```

```css
.but {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: black;
}

#button1 {
  left: 33%;
  background-color: black;
  color: blue;
  color: blue;
}

#button2 {
  right: 33%;
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="container" style="width:100%">
  <button id="button1" class="but">1</button>
  <button id="button2" class="but">2</button>
</div>
<button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Just one last question. How do I make it choose the new win item directly after clicking ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When I click on a box it tells me if I won or lost and that's working great but I'd like to recalculate the win item right after without having to refresh the page. I was thinking of creating a button for that but I'm not sure how to make it a function in JavaScript.

Comment: See update. It is a bit more complex but is using recommended practices.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` is just for test not for use in real world, don't use it in your work, rather you can create a div or  a modal that for example will have a class or id `#modal` and use `innerHTML` to show your results;

```
document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = your results
```

Answer (score 0):

create a paragrapg with an id
get the ID of the paragraph
and use .innerhtml to add the output

```
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML='you win;
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button id="button1" onclick="checkIsWin(1)" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; position: absolute; left: 33%; background-color: black; color: blue;">1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="checkIsWin(2)" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; position: absolute; right: 33%; background-color: black; color: red;">2</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function checkIsWin(buttonNum) {
  document.getElementById('container').innerText = (buttonNum === winItem ? "You won" : "You lose");
}
```